# How to Change the forward vector in unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just can't figure out how to change the forward vector of an object in unity, Please tell me how that's all I really want to know.

Comment: Forward is always forward. But there is vector3.forward which is globally "north" and then transform.forward which is where you face.

Comment: Quite unclear what you are asking. Per definition in Unity "forward" always refers to the `Z` axis, either global or local. If you mean you want to give an object a different default orientation I would make it a child of an empty object, rotate it accordingly in that local space and rather use this new parent object's forward which is still he default Z axis while the nested child can have any other rotation making it point towards a different direction

Answer (score 1):

You would use `transform.forward` for that instead. `Vector3.forward` is a static variable (only a single copy exists and is shared between everything) and is the same for every object. However, `transform.forward` is specific to the object and changes when said object rotates.

TLDR: `transform.forward` instead of `Vector3.forward`